# React Vite App not capturing elements in Chrome (but works as expected in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following bit of code

```js
let userInput, terminalOutput;

const keyboard = () => {
  userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
  terminalOutput = document.getElementById("terminalTextArea");
  document.getElementById("dummy-Keyboard").focus();
  console.log("keyboard running");
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", keyboard);
```

It's imported from my main.jsx file at line 4

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.js";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

There are other helper functions surrounding the keyboard function which take keyboard input in and append them to a box within the dom. This func and the rest work as expected within Firefox but the root of the issue is that when attempting to run in chrome I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')
```

Attempting to log my variables (after setting them to objects in the DOM) logs them as null within Chrome, but they're correctly grabbed within Firefox.

I've attempted using both the ReactDevTools and the built in browser tools with them also giving the same issue of only working within Mozilla but returning null for all my variables within Chrome.

Not understanding why they're being recognized and read correctly within Firefox but not Chrome

Comment: Is `dummy-Keyboard` in the html? Or do you add it using react? If you are adding it using react it's weird that it works at all in any browser

Comment: @Konrad yeah it's added within a react module